# How to Rename 12 identifier in a tlb file, using one "rename" #import attribute

Tags: visual-c++, warnings

On migrating a VC++ 6.0 developed code to Visual studio 2008, I got the below warnings pointing one line of code.

Warning Message:

```
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'GetCurrentDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'SetCurrentDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'DeleteFile': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'CreateDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'RemoveDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'CreateDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'GetUserName': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'GetFullPathName': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'SearchPath': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'ShellExecute': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'DeleteFile': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
1>c:\Test\File1.h(8) : warning C4278: 'GetTempPath': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier
```

Error Code Line:

```
#import "GCRComp.tlb" rename_namespace("GCRTools")
```

I fixed this issue for the first warning for "GetCurrentDirectory" by using "rename" attribute. Code below,

```
#import "GCRComp.tlb" rename_namespace("GCRTools"), rename("GetCurrentDirectory","GetCurrentDirectoryNew")
```

As this only fixed 1 warning, how do I fix the remaining 11 warnings, As the challenge is all the 11 warnings also points to the same #import code.

Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you already know the answer, you need another 11 *rename* directives.  Use a \ backslash to write them on separate lines.

There does get to be a point where the warning outlives its usefulness.  It was added to later VS versions because the damage done by the preprocessor to these identifiers can generate such horribly difficult to diagnose error messages.  Many a programmer has lost clumps of head hair trying to figure out where "GetCurrentDirectoryW" came from.  Or worse, why "GetCurrentDirectory()" in his code produces an "identifier not found" compile error even though it is clearly visible in the type library and the .tlh file.

But that's not a problem you have, these identifiers were already getting renamed back when you compiled the code in VC6.  As long as they are renamed *consistently* throughout the source code and are not externally visible then you don't have a problem.  Which is very common.  So just disable the warning and move ahead with your life:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4278)
#import "GCRComp.tlb" rename_namespace("GCRTools")
```

Comment: I do agree pragma warning is a way to disable this warning. But I'm just asking out of curiosity, can you please write and show me how you rename more than one identifier may be two. You told me to use \ backslash, But I'm not able to write it correctly. This might also help somebody who face the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a , comma.  Type \ and press Enter.